# I'm having API connection problem on netlifiy

Tags: api, netlify

https://github.com/herrbaha/reactweather This is the github address of my code, I want to publish it on netlfiy, I have followed the steps and received an address (https://reactweatherbaha.netlify.app/). This link opens the page, but there is a problem with the API and the information is not coming.

Comment: "there is a problem with the api" What problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

When running the search on the site, there is a console error to the `api` endpoint because the call is using an insecure call (`http`). Try using `https` for the uri.

```js
async function getdata(value) {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const data = await fetch(
        `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${API_KEY}&q=${value}&days=3&aqi=no&alerts=no`
      );
      const result = await data.json();
      setWheatherData(result.forecast.forecastday);
      setError(false);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setError(true);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you could mark this as the correct answer, it will help others to see it worked right away. Glad it worked for you.